# How to sort all elements of a 2d matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, sorting

The sort() function sorts the elements row/column wise but how to sort the elements absolutely? The result should be another matrix with smallest element in (1,1) , second smallest in (1,2) and so on.

Comment: What shape do you want the result? Just flatten the array, sort, and reshape as desired.

Comment: 'A(:) = sort(A(:))' may sort so that reading column by column from letf to right would go in increasing order ... but your question is unclear ... the column operator ':' here just serve as taking the elements one after the other to vectorise things (columnwise)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take some random input

```
input = rand(5,10);
```

If you want the output to be a row vector, simply use

```
sortedRow = sort(input(:)).';
```

If you want the result to be the same shape as the input, then use

```
sortedOriginalShape = reshape(sort(input(:)), size(input,2), size(input,1)).';
```

Note that when maintaining the shape, we must use the reversed `size` dimensions and then transpose. This is because otherwise the result is column-wise i.e. smallest element in (1,1), next in (2,1) etc, which is the opposite of what you requested.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the column operator (`:`) to vectorize all elements of 'nxm' matrix as a vector of 'nxm' elements and sort this vector. Then you can use direct assignement or 'reshape' function to store elements as matricial form.

All you need to know is that matlab use [column-major-ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) to vectorize/iterate elements:

```
A = rand(3, 5);
A(:) = sort(A(:);
```

Will preserve colum-major-ordering, or as you said you prefer row-major ordering:

```
A = rand(3, 5);
A = reshape(sort(A(:)), fliplr(size(A)).';
```

Note the `fliplr` to store columnwise with reversed dimension and then the `.'` operator to transpose again the result.

**EDIT**

Even if matlab uses column-major-ordering for storing elements in memory, here below are two generic routines to work with row-major-order whatever the number of dimension of your array (i.e. no limited to 2D):

```
function [vector] = VectorizeWithRowMajorOrdering(array)
%[
    axisCount = length(size(array)); % Squeezed size of original array
    permutation = fliplr(1:(axisCount + 2)); % +2 ==> Trick to vectorize data in correct order
    vector = permute(array, permutation);
    vector = vector(:);
%]
end

function [array] = ReshapeFromRowMajorOrdering(vector, siz)
%[
    siz = [siz( : ).' 1]; % Fix size if only one dim
    array = NaN(siz); % Init
    axisCount = length(size(array)); % Squeezed size!
    permutation = fliplr(1:(axisCount + 2)); % +2 ==> Trick to vectorize data in correct order

    array = reshape(vector, [1 1 fliplr(size(array))]);
    array = ipermute(array, permutation);
%]
end
```

This can be useful when working with data coming from C/C++ (these languages use row-major-ordering). In your case this can be used this way:

```
A = rand(3, 5);
A = ReshapeFromRowMajorOrdering(sort(A(:)), size(A));
```